# Empty Textarea / Disable Submit for period

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation

I have a problem where I don't know the solution:

I have a form with a small basic validation that only checks if textarea is empty or not.

If it's empty: if-loop should result in the following actions:

1. Show a message (and fade out).
2. Add a class to submitbutton (black, for "visited")
3. Add "disabled-attribute" to the button
4. Wait a period (5000ms)
   undo steps 2. and 3., make button clickable again, if it's clicked again with the emptytextarea play game step 1-4 again and again.

My function:

```
$("#abschleppform").submit(function() {
    if($("#abschleppkennzeichen").val() == ""){
        $("#response").html("<p>Please enter your text!</p>").fadeOut(5000);
        $("#submitabschleppdienst").attr("disabled", true).addClass("black"); 
         setTimeout(function(){
             $("#submitabschleppdienst").attr("disabled", false).removeClass("black"); 
          }, 5000);
    }
    else {
        alert("Message has been sent");
        /*$.ajax({
            url: "kundenzufriedenheit/abschleppkundenzufriedenheit.php",
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            cache: false,                    
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(msg)
                {
                    $("#response").html(msg);
                    $("#response").fadeOut(5000);
                }
        });*/
       $("#submitabschleppdienst").attr("disabled", true).addClass("black"); 
    }
    return false;
});
```

My html:

```
<form action = "kundenzufriedenheit/abschleppkundenzufriedenheit.php" method = "POST" id="abschleppform" class="contact-form">
    <h4 class="first">Kennzeichen</h4>
    <textarea rows="5" id="abschleppkennzeichen" class="kennzeichen" type="text" name="abschleppkennzeichen" ></textarea>
    <input type="submit" id="submitabschleppdienst" value="Absenden">
    <div id="response"></div>
    <div id="response_2"></div>

</form>
```

Running: https://jsfiddle.net/tigercode/60f55L9q/16/

Problem: sending the empty textarea, it doesn't reset to play the steps above (message / disable / enable ...) again. The meesage only shows up once.

Can anybody help me?
Best,
tiger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can understand, the only thing you're missing in your function is making the #response visible again. This can be accomplished like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#submitabschleppdienst").attr("disabled", false).removeClass("black"); 
    $('#response').html('').fadeIn(0);   
}, 5000);
```

Once this is added, your JSFiddle behaves in the manner your question described.

Answer (score 0):

That's it! Sometimes the correct answer is so easy... and I was slow on the uptake ... "fadeout" doesn't kill text inside the div, it kills the whole div with content inside. After clicking the second time, it doesn't find my div id="response" to display the text again ^^, so I have to restore the div first...

Kind regards,
tiger